# Whenever I try to execute the program it says" Pizza does not refer to an value" Can somebody explain why

Tags: c++, class, oop, variables, distinct-values

Whenever I try to execute the program it says" Pizza does not refer to an value" Can somebody explain why.

Please note that I am using Xcode on Mac OS X Monterey

I am following Rob Percials The Complete C++ Developer Course and on class no. 60 it is a Pizza class project. The objective is to make a pizza class. I try to configure this yet it gives mistake someone please help me thank you.

The source code

!!!!!!! HEADER FILE !!!!!!!!

```
#ifndef test_h
#define test_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Pizza {
public:
    Pizza(string name, int cost, int diametre);
    void addtopping(string topping);
    string getname() ;
    int getdiametre();
    int getcost() ;
    void printtoppings() ;
private:
    string name;
    int cost;
    int diametre;
    vector<string>toppings;
    
};

#endif /* test_h */
```

!!!!! THE PIZZA CPP !!!!

```
type here

#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
Pizza::Pizza(string name, int cost, int diametre){
    this->name=name;
    this->cost=cost;
    this->diametre=diametre;
    toppings.push_back("cheese");
};
void Pizza::addtopping(string topping){
    toppings.push_back(topping);
}
string Pizza::getname() {
    return name;
}
int Pizza::getdiametre() {
    return diametre;
}
int Pizza::getcost() {
    return cost;
}
void Pizza::printtoppings() {
    for (string topping:toppings) {
        cout<<"\t"<<topping<<endl;
    }
}
```

!!!MAIN CPP!!!!

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;
void printpizzadata(const Pizza& pizza);
int main(){

    Pizza John("Cheesy boi",5,8);
    Pizza matt("meaty boi",7,8);
    matt.addtopping("peppers");
    Pizza special("special boi",12,10);
    special.addtopping("onions");
    special.addtopping("black olives");
    special.addtopping("mushroom");
    special.addtopping("peppers");
    printpizzadata(John);
    printpizzadata(matt);
    printpizzadata(special);
    return 0;
}
void printpizzadata(const Pizza& pizza){
    int a;
    cout<<"Name"<<Pizza.getname<<endl; /* this is where the issue occurs */
    cout<<"Diametre"<<Pizza.getdiametre()<<endl; /* this is where the issue occurs */
    cout<<"cost"<<Pizza.getcost()<<endl; /* this is where the issue occurs */
    cout<<"Toppings:"<<Pizza.printtoppings()<<endl; /* this is where the issue occurs */
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}
```

I Wass following the tutor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use object name `pizza` instead of class name `Pizza`. Also when you call a function put `()`:

```
cout<<"Name"<<pizza.getname()<<endl;
```

Comment: When I do that it gives me this error for each: 'this' argument to member function 'getname' has type 'const Pizza', but function is not marked const. When I remove const it gives me Undefined symbol: printpizzadata(Pizza const&). Please help

Comment: Make `getname`, `getdiametre`, etc. `const` member functions. Your materials should have already covered the difference between `const` and non-`const` member functions.

Comment: I know the difference between const and non const member functions and since I know the difference I tried that already a while ago and it just gave double the errors

Comment: @chaitanyakurakula "I tried that already" we cannot possibly guess what exactly you did wrong unless you show us your attempt.